# Javascript function syntax in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This may even be more of a generic Javascript(possibly es6) question, but here lets see how it plays out.

I encounter this type of syntax daily, and am beginning to become annoyed that I do not understand how this stuff is working under the hood:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore)
```

I can see that applyMiddleware is obviously a function, that in this example, is taking reduxThunk as an argument. However, I have no clue what createStore is doing sitting in parentheses next to it.

Same can go for this example, where I am confused about what's going on with UserList:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList)
```

Could anyone explain to me what is going on here? An explanation of both would be appreciated, as they both serve different purposes, and one ends up being an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore)
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
const temp = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = temp(createStore);
```

*(But without the `temp` variable.)*

The code is calling `applyMiddleware` with the argument `reduxThunk`; `applyMiddleware` returns a *function*. Then, the code is calling that function with the `createStore` argument.

Here's a simple example with no libs or similar:

```js
function createAdder(valueToAdd) {
    return function(valueToAddTo) {
        return valueToAddTo + valueToAdd;
    };
}

// Doing it all at once
const result1 = createAdder(5)(10);
console.log(result1); // 15

// Doing it step by step
const addFiveTo = createAdder(5);
const result2 = addFiveTo(10);
console.log(result2); // 15
```

Comment: Brilliantly explained. Cleared up a major gap.

Answer (score 1):

I is a way of calling a function that returns another function so the definition of applyMiddleware will look something like

```
const applyMiddleware = (middleware) => {
     return (store) => {
          // some modification here
          return somethinghere;
     }
}
```

so the two argument that you see are first to the outer function and then to the returned function.

Similarly `connect` also returns a function the first et of arguments are to the connect function and the second set of arguments to the function returned by it.

The call

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList)
```

is equivalent of

```
var connectStateProps = connect(mapStateToProps);
export default connectStateProps(UserList);
```

Comment: This was pretty helpful. I appreciate the response.